# How To Remove Line Break from Teatarea in processmaker

Tags: javascript, jquery, processmaker

I created a output document , in each Textarea and Textbox there is a line break i want to know how to remove it

Answer (score 0):

Line break are usually "\n". So if you want to output or show it in a "div" tag, then you go with this code:

```js
function formatData(){

var inpData = document.getElementById("textInput").value.split("\n");
var outputData = "";
for(var i = 0;i < inpData.length; i++){

outputData += inpData[i];

}

document.getElementById("textOutput").innerHTML = outputData;

}
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" id="textInput"></textarea>
<button onclick="formatData()">Display Formatted Data</button>
<div id="textOutput"></div>
```